# Why is this Shift Register not loading properly in VHDL?

Tags: loading, vhdl, shift-register

I have a custom designed shift register that has as input DL(leftmost input), DR(rightmost), CLR that clears and loads DR, S that shifts right and W that loads leftmost. After testing it, the rightmost is being loaded but not the left. I have reread the code multiple times, but I can't figure out what is wrong. Here's the code:

```
    library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity shiftregister is
    port (
        CLK, CLR: in STD_LOGIC;
        S: in STD_LOGIC; --Shift right
 W: in STD_LOGIC; --Write
 Cin: in STD_LOGIC; --possible carry in from the addition
        DL: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0); --left load for addition result
 DR: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0); --right load for initial multiplier
        Q: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0)
     );
end shiftregister ;

architecture shiftregister of shiftregister is
signal IQ: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0):= (others => '0');
begin
   process (CLK)
   begin
 if(CLK'event and CLK='1') then 
          if CLR = '1' then 
   IQ(7 downto 0)  <= DR;  --CLR clears and initializes the multiplier
   IQ(15 downto 8) <= (others => '0');
   else 
  if (S='1') then
    IQ <= Cin & IQ(15 downto 1);
  elsif (W='1') then
    IQ(15 downto 8) <= DL;
  end if;
          end if;

 end if;  
    end process;
Q<=IQ;
end shiftregister;
```

#### Waveform

[image: waveform]

[image]

#### TestBench

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity register_tb is
end register_tb;

architecture register_tb of register_tb is
    component shiftregister is port (
        CLK, CLR: in STD_LOGIC;
        S: in STD_LOGIC; --Shift right
        W: in STD_LOGIC; --Write
        Cin: in STD_LOGIC; --possible carry in from the addition
        DL: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0); --left load for addition result
        DR: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0); --right load for initial multiplier
        Q: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0)
    );
    end component;

    signal CLK: std_logic:='0';
    signal CLR: std_logic:='1';
    signal Cin: std_logic:='0';
    signal S: std_logic:='1';
    signal W: std_logic:='0';
    signal DL, DR: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0):="00000000";
    signal Q: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0):="0000000000000000";
begin 
    U0: shiftregister port map (CLK, CLR, S, W, Cin, DL,DR,Q);

    CLR <= not CLR    after 20 ns;
    CLK <= not CLK    after 5 ns;
    W   <= not W      after 10 ns;
    DL  <= "10101010" after 10 ns;
    DR  <= "00110011" after 10 ns;

end register_tb;
```

Comment: How is it not working? Could you show an example input / output that does not produce the expected output? Perhaps as a waveform from chipscope / signaltap?

Comment: And additionally, I'm not sure I'd be comfortable calling something that you can write to any part of the fifo a shift register...

Comment: From a quick scan, it looks like what you've written is what is happening. Could you additionally point out where the behavior of the waveform is different from what you expected?

Comment: @BillLynch When CLR is 1, it is not loading the rightmost bits, DR,   ` if CLR = '1' then`
                `IQ <= (others => '0');`
                `IQ(7 downto 0) <= DR;`

Comment: @BillLynch Any thoughts on what might be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your simulation shows that your `S` input is always high. The way you have your conditions setup, this means that the last elsif statement will not execute because `S` has priority over `W`. If you want your write to have priority over your shift operation, you should switch your conditions

```
if (W='1') then
  IQ(15 downto 8) <= DL;
elsif (S='1') then
  IQ <= Cin & IQ(15 downto 1);
end if;
```

Based on your comment for the desired behaviour, you could do something like this:

```
if (S='1' and W='1') then
  IQ  <= Cin & DL & IQ(7 downto 1);
elsif (W='1') then -- S=0
  IQ(15 downto 8) <= DL;
elsif (S='1') then -- W=0
  IQ <= Cin & IQ(15 downto 1);
end if; -- W=0 & S=0
```

Comment: It fixes the problem but Is there a way to make it do both when S=1 and W=1, because that is what I want it to do

Comment: Depends what you want your end result to be when both `W` and `S` are `1`. Do you want the upper byte of `IQ` to be set to `DL` while still shifting the lower byte? What happens to `Cin` in this case?

Comment: Cin is meant to be a 0.So we can just ignore it and append a 0

Comment: Is it possible to set the upper byte of IQ to DL THEN shift the whole output?

Comment: Take a look at the edit. Might not be exactly what you want, but you should be able to use the same concepts

Answer (score 2):

Some improvements:

(1) Remove all signal but CLK from sensitivity list. Your process has no async signals, so only clock is needed in sensitivity list.

```
process(CLK)
```

(2) Assign zero only to the required bits -> question of taste ;)

```
IQ(7 downto 0)  <= DR;              --CLR clears and initializes the multiplier
IQ(15 downto 8) <= (others => '0');
```

(3) A elsif statement can clarify the assignment precedence:

```
if (S='1') then
  IQ <= Cin & IQ(15 downto 1);
elsif (W='1') then
  IQ(15 downto 8) <= DL;
end if;
```

(4) Line `Q <= IQ;` produces a second 16-bit register. I think this is not intended. Move this line outside of the process.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I implemented your changes, but I got 0's instead of X's

Comment: Can you post a new waveform with an extended view on signal Q, so we can see the lower and upper byte? I would also suggest to reduce  the speed of signal `W` so we can see the shifting. Improvement (5): signal IQ should have a initial value: `signal IQ: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := (others => '0');` - If you have changed your code on your computer, please edit your question as well, so we can see the current version of your code :)

Comment: I will upload it a few

Comment: I think that everything is working as intended, does it? Note: Your clock is starting with a phase of 180° (1/2 period delayed) this causes the strange waveform. I would suggest to set the default value of CLK to '1'.

Comment: pwolfsbergs answer fixes the problem but it changes my desired output. I want a case where both S and W can be 1

Comment: Two input signals `S` and `W` leads to 4 combinations. The current solution covers all 4 combinations. 00 -> save; 01 -> shift; 1* -> write (* means don't care). What sould the circuit do on 11?

Comment: When it is 11, it should set the upper byte of IQ to DL then shift the whole output.